# Best way to make hyperlink open on second tap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have image tiles on my website, for want of a better description.

On mobile, I would like a single tap on one of these tiles to bring up some more text (describing the content of that section), before a second tap  actually navigates to that link and opens the new page.

At the same time, on desktop I would like a hover of the mouse to reveal the hidden text, before a click navigates to that section.

I had thought I could simply use hover - having read before that a single tap on touch based devices imitates hover, before a second tap opens the link. However, this doesn't appear to be the case for me - if I use hover, E.G:

```
<a class="tileLink" href="/projects/london-serviced-apartments">
    <section class="tile">    
        <img src="/images/lsa-s.jpg" srcset="/images/lsa-m.jpg 600w, /images/lsa-l.jpg 1000w, /images/lsa-xl.jpg 1920w" alt="services" />
        <h1>London Serviced Apartments</h1>
        <p class="hidden">Test hover text</p>
    </section>  
</a>

.tileLink:hover .tile{
    opacity: 0.75;
}

.tileLink:hover p{
    display: inline;
}
```

when I tap once on one of the tiles, the hidden text displays briefly but then the link is immediately navigated to - so the user is taken directly to that section before having had a chance to read the text and decide if they want to open the link or not.

I did try doing this using Javascript:

```
$(".tileLink").click(function(e){
        if( $(this).find(".tile").hasClass("tapped") ){

        }else{
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).find(".tile").addClass("tapped").find("p").removeClass("hidden");
        }
});
```

which actually works fine for mobile, but then on desktop hover doesn't work - a click is needed to display the hidden text, and a second click is needed to navigate to that section.

Is there a simple way of doing this that will work across multiple devices?

Comment: Do you mean that irrespective of the click behavior the hidden <p> is not shown on desktop on mouseover? Because that would be a different issue, your `.tileLink:hover p` might not have authority over your `.hidden`, could you post that as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could give a try to `pointer-events` to allow click only once parent of `<a>` is focused.

I assume your links might be in a list (or else).

below a snippet to test the idea.

*best is, i guess, to manage this via javascript to make it bulllet proof *

*mediaquerie doesn't seem reliable to filter only touch screen, small yes.*

```css
.tileLink:hover .tile,
.tileLink:focus .tile {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.tileLink:hover p,
.tileLink:focus p {
  display: inline;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  pointer-events: none;
}

li:focus a,
li:hover a {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>test double click to trigger link </h1>
<ul>
  <li tabindex="0">
    <a class="tileLink" href="/projects/london-serviced-apartments">
      <section class="tile">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200" srcset="http://dummyimage.com/300 600w,http://dummyimage.com/400 1000w, http://dummyimage.com/400 1920w" alt="services" />
        <h1>London Serviced Apartments</h1>
        <p class="hidden">Test hover text</p>
      </section>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

to play with the idea  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYyKJv http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwbWRB

Comment: This worked best for me, I like that it's pure CSS too. Hadn't come across pointer-events before. I don't have my tiles in a list, so improvised slightly by containing each tile within its own div instead of li's. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Heres a codepen](http://codepen.io/jakebown/pen/YyPawz) of what you're looking for - you can do a check to see if the device is mobile like so

```
var isMobile = false;
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  isMobile = true;
}
if(isMobile) {
  $(".tileLink").on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var para = $(this).find('p.hidden');
     if(para.hasClass('tapped')) {
       window.location = $(this).attr('href');
     } else {
       $('p.hidden').removeClass('hidden').addClass('tapped');
     }
  });
} else {
  $('.tileLink').on('mouseover', function() {
     $(this).find('p.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
  });
}
```